# I'm trying to use Firebase DataBase and Firebase Messaging into my Flutter app

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I'm trying to use Firebase Database and Firebase Messaging into my Flutter App. But when I include the firebase libraries through pubspec.yaml and try do run it on iOS, I get the following error -

> Xcode's output:
>       clang: error: -fobjc-weak is not supported on the current deployment target

Here is how I am including Firebase in my pubspec.yaml file -

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.0
  shared_preferences: ^0.3.2
  intl: ^0.15.2
  firebase_database: 0.3.5
  firebase_messaging: ^0.1.3
```

Any idea on how to go about solving this ?

Comment: Did you add the google-info.plist file in the project?

Comment: Yes, I have added it.

Comment: did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: Seems to be fixed by changing the pod settings (Pods -> TARGETS -> (nanopb or firebase_messaging, or any other offending pod) -> iOS Development Target to iOS8.0) but I'm not sure it's the proper fix.